# SendInput doesn't send chars or numbers

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard

I've got something like that:

```
void generateKeybdEvent(int vk, bool extended) {
    KEYBDINPUT kb = {0};
    INPUT Input = {0};

    if ( extended )
        kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
    kb.wVk = vk;
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki = kb;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

    ZeroMemory(&kb, sizeof(KEYBDINPUT));
    ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    if ( extended )
        kb.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;

    kb.wVk = vk;
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki = kb;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
}
```

When I send inputs 'A', CapsLock, 'A':

```
generateKeybdEvent ('A', false);
generateKeybdEvent (VK_CAPITAL, true);
generateKeybdEvent ('A', false);
```

The only effect is that my num lock toggles.

Why I cant send characters or numbers to apps?

Note I'm using Windows 7 with Polish keyboard layout and Qt with MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

`VK_CAPITAL` is not extended key.
Key is extended if `(vk >= 33 && vk <= 46) || (vk >= 91 && vk <= 93)`.

Also `ZeroMemory` can be omitted here, so your function could look like this:

```
KEYBDINPUT kb = {0};
INPUT Input = {0};

if ( (vk >= 33 && vk <= 46) || (vk >= 91 && vk <= 93) )
    kb.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;

kb.wVk = vk;
Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki = kb;

SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
kb.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
```

And the most important thing: **Problem is probably not in this function**. I guess that input is sent, but to the wrong window. Use [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to direct this input (call it before you call [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

You should also check [SendInput](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html) on 
pinvoke.net